# Passing strings in value field in pyscopg2

Tags: python, psycopg2

Sorry this is a very newbie question.  When I'm trying to pass a tuple into an insert statement the quotations seem to disappear.

```
line=[0, 1, 3000248, 'G', 'T', 102, 102, 60, 25]
SNPinfo = tuple(line) 
curs.execute("""INSERT INTO akr (code, chrID, chrLOC, refBase, conBase, \
consqual, SNPqual, maxMapqual, numbReadBases) \
VALUES (%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s)""", SNPinfo)
```

**The Error I get is**:
LINE 1: ...axMapqual, numbReadBases)     VALUES (0,1,3000248,G,T,102,10..
psycopg2.ProgrammingError: column "g" does not exist

I think my insert statement is wrong somewhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing the single quotes around the varchars on your string formatting:

```
curs.execute("""INSERT INTO akr (code, chrID, chrLOC, refBase, conBase, \
consqual, SNPqual, maxMapqual, numbReadBases) \
VALUES (%s,%s,%s,'%s','%s',%s,%s,%s,%s)""", SNPinfo)
```

This would produce:

```
INSERT INTO akr (code, chrID, chrLOC, refBase, conBase,
consqual, SNPqual, maxMapqual, numbReadBases) 
VALUES (0,1,3000248,'G','T',102,102,60,25)
```